# I keep getting "Error Querying Database" in PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Looks like I'm connecting to the server just fine. The problem seems to happen when it runs the query. It keeps saying

> Error Querying Database

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
 $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'elvis_store')
      or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

 $first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
 $last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];

 $query = "INSERT INTO email_list (first_name, last_name, email)" .
      "VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";
 mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
      or die('Error querying database.');

 echo 'Customer added.';

 mysqli_close($dbc);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because in your MySQLi connection you only give a location and username. You do not give a database name to be used. if you have no password, you need to write your connection like this:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'elvis_store', NULL, 'dbName)
```

or

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'dbUsername', NULL, 'elvis_store')
```

if "elvis_store" is the database name and not the username. Remember, a mysqli connection is: `mysqli_connect(dbLocation, dbUsername, dbPassword, dbName)`.

Also, as Ed has pointed out in another answer, there is also a syntax error in your MySQL statement. Here is the snippet from Ed's answer:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO email_list (first_name, last_name, email) " . "VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";
```

Comment: Actually I have no user name or password. The 'elvis_store' is the database name.

Comment: @Duke In that case, you can put `NULL` (No quotes) in the username slot as well. The `mysqi()` constructor takes certain information in a certain order, so if you are going to skip something you have to use the `NULL` keyword.

Comment: I didn't down vote anything, actually I appreciate you guys help.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems.

## Problem 1: Syntax error

Your query has a typo (a missing space). Your query code

```
$query = "INSERT INTO email_list (first_name, last_name, email)" .
 "VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";
```

produces this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO email_list (first_name, last_name, email)VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')
--                                                   ^ syntax error, missing space
```

To fix it, change your code to this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO email_list (first_name, last_name, email) " .
 "VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";
```

At least for testing purposes, you probably should look at the output of [**`mysqli_error()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) instead of using a generic message like `Error querying database`. Even in production, you'll want to trap and log the real error *somehow*.

---

## Problem 2: You don't select a database

Edit: I missed this in my first glance at your question, but as Stephen Cioffi points out, you also need to select a database before running your query. You can do this with the schema parameter to `mysqli_connect()` or by using [**`mysqli_db_select()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php).

Both of these issues—the typo and the failure to select a database—will cause problems; you must fix both.

---

## Problem 3: Huge SQL Injection Vulnerability

This is not strictly part of the answer, but it's important. You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). You need to use prepared statements. Otherwise, you are going to get hacked. Imagine that the POSTed `firstname` is this:

```
', (SELECT CONCAT(username, ',', password) FROM users WHERE is_admin = 1), 'eviluser@example.com') --
```

Your query becomes (with some added formatting):

```
INSERT INTO email_list (first_name, last_name, email)
VALUES ('',
    (SELECT CONCAT(username, ',', password) FROM users WHERE is_admin = 1),
    'eviluser@example.com'
) -- ', 'value of lastname', 'value of email')
```

Then, when you email your users, somebody's going to get an email with a recipient like

```
"Duke,mySup3rP@ssw0rd!" <eviluser@example.com>
```

And... you're hosed.

(Hopefully, you're salting and hashing passwords, but still, this is disastrous.) You *must* use prepared statements.

Comment: I have no username or passwords to use. 'elvis_store' is the name of the database.

Comment: @Duke Take a look at how to use the parameters for [**`mysqli_connect()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php); they're specified [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php). You need to provide a host, user name, password, then database name, in that order. You can't just provide the host and then the database name. If you're really not going to use a user name or password (VERY unlikely), you're probably better off doing just `mysqli_connect('localhost')` and then `mysqli_db_select('elvis_store')` separately.

Comment: Thanks guys!!! I took your advice and added a user name and password via phpMyadmin. After I set that I modified the config file to match the password and user name, then went back to my php file and added the user name and password to mysqli_connect and now everything works. It added my contact to my email list. Thanks a lot!